# C# folder permissions

Tags: c#, permissions

I need to take ownership of the folder and it's subfolders in order to delete it. Manual process works for me fine:

1. Open folder properties.
2. Security tab -> Advanced -> Owner Change -> check "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects"
3. Messagebox appears: *You do not have permission to read the contents of directory C:\a4f31eae62bde1cb4d49834897\Sandbox. Do you want to replace the directory permissions with permissions granting you Full Control?
   All permissions will be replaced if you press Yes.*
4. Press Yes
5. Then I'm able to delete the folder.

But I have around hundred of these folders ([reason](https://www.windows10forums.com/threads/random-guid-folder-are-being-creted-on-my-c-drive.8599/)) so I'd like to delete them programmatically.

My code takes ownership of the folder but not the subfolders.

```
var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
var dirSecurity = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();

dirSecurity.SetOwner(identity);

var fullControlRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(identity, 
    FileSystemRights.FullControl,
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, 
    PropagationFlags.None, 
    AccessControlType.Allow);

dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(fullControlRule);
dirInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSecurity);
```

When trying to delete the folder afterwards I get *System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\a4f31eae62bde1cb4d49834897\Sandbox' is denied.*

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: tried running vs as admin ?

Comment: For the subfolders have you considered making a recursive function?

Comment: Yes, VS runs as admin.

When trying to set permissions recursively, I get _System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'_ when calling _dirInfo.GetAccessControl()_ on _Sanbox_ subfolder. I don't have even read permission on these subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution that worked for me was using *takeover* from commandline (PowerShell). Though I'm still insterested in C# solution...

Thanks to user who deleted his advice afterwards.

Final PowerShell code to clear mentioned folders:

```
$dirNames = Get-ChildItem "C:\" | Select-String -Pattern "[a-f0-9]{18,30}"

foreach ($dirName in $dirNames) {
    TakeOver("C:\$dirName")
}

function TakeOver($dirPath) {
    takeown /f $dirPath /r /d Y
    #icacls $dirPath /reset /T
}
```

- *takeown* worked as expected (recursively for subfolders).
- *icacls* was not needed in my case, it was possible to delete folders afterwards.